# What is the name of this matrix decomposition?

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I have used a matrix decomposition in my work that a different author calls “asymmetric Schur decomposition”. Now I am trying to find a reference for this and found that the Schur decomposition is usually of a different form, namely with three matrices. From the overall form it more looks like an LU-decomposition, but Mathematica gives me a different result when decomposing this matrix.

Could you tell me what type of decomposition this is?

$$
    M =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        M_\mathrm{ee} & M_\mathrm{eo} \\
        M_\mathrm{oe} & M_\mathrm{oo}
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        M_\mathrm{ee} & \mathbf 0 \\
        M_\mathrm{oe} & \mathbf 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbf 1 & M_\mathrm{ee}^{-1} M_\mathrm{eo} \\
        \mathbf 0 & M_\mathrm{oo} - M_\mathrm{oe} M_\mathrm{ee}^{-1} M_\mathrm{eo}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just an LU decomposition in which the diagonal of L was not turned into $1$s. LU is not really unique if only the triangular shapes are required.

Think of an LU decomposition as performing row reduction of a matrix to upper triangular form. It can be done in many ways.